# Animation using Class Name in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to animate a div by adding a CSS class name to it on click of a button. But this works only for the first time. Next time I click the button and add the CSS class name, it doesn't animate the div. What am I doing wrong here?

```
<head>
<script>
function abc() {
 document.getElementById("a").className = "";
 document.getElementById("a").className = document.getElementById("a").className + " b";
}
</script>
<style> 
#a {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
 position:relative;
}
.b {
 animation-name:myfirst;
 animation-duration:5s; 
 animation-timing-function:linear;
 animation-delay:2s;
 animation-iteration-count:1;
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-play-state:running;
}

@keyframes myfirst
{
 0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
 25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
 50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
 75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
 100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
 0%   {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
 25%  {background:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
 50%  {background:blue; left:200px; top:200px;}
 75%  {background:green; left:0px; top:200px;}
 100% {background:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="a" class="c"></div>
<button onclick="abc()">Click</button>

</body>
```

Comment: The second time you add the class nothing happens because the element already has it. Classes are a binary switch. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes on a given element are a set, so adding one that’s already there doesn’t change anything. This kind of animation would probably be better done using JavaScript. (In practice, CSS animation is like anything in CSS — it depends on state, not actions.)

Or am I misunderstanding? Is the problem that it doesn’t stop?

Since you’re using animations, it’s probably safe to assume `classList` support, so:

```
document.getElementById("a").classList.toggle("b");
```

Comment: Hi, on click of the button, 1st I am clearing the class names, if any and then I am setting the desired class name. So that's not the problem here.

Comment: @sidrocks: Clearing it first does nothing; the browser doesn’t actually apply any changes to the CSS until the JavaScript is done running, which is why it’s the wrong thing to use.

Comment: @sidrocks: But after all, [there is an ugly hack for any problem](http://codepen.io/minitech/pen/dnKoJ).

Comment: @sidrocks have a look at this [transition.js](https://github.com/icodebuster/transition.js).